# SAS, split the data by char levels

Tags: sas

I have a data set (test1) and I want to divide it into two or more data sets. 
The first column is repeat of sequence, and the second column is a var with different levels (can be 2, 3, 4 or more). what I need to do is to automatically (so if var2 = a will not work) split the data by the levels from second columns. The reason I what this automation is the second variable varies, sometime it has 3 levels, sometime 2, so I cannot use fix statement. Thank you.

```
data test1;
input var1$ var2$ ;
datalines;

1 a 
2 a 
3 a 
1 b 
2 b 


;
run;

data test1_output1;
input var1$ var2$ ;
datalines;

1 a 
2 a 
3 a 
;
run;


data test1_output2;
input var1$ var2$ ;
datalines;

1 b 
2 b 

;
run;
```

Comment: you need to explain what you are trying to do.  also show code of what you've tried.  examples of input and desired output.

Comment: Asked earlier this week already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49805173/splitting-a-sas-dataset-into-multiple-datasets-according-to-value-of-one-variab  Otherwise, check the links in the comments there that demonstrate several dynamic methods.

Comment: And as always, usually ignored, this is not a good practice to start and usually increases your workload downstream.

Comment: Please do not split data.  SAS has very suitable features such as the `WHERE` statement or `WHERE=` data set option and `BY` statement for group-wise processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dataset can be sorted , i.e. it has unique and distinct levels, then follow below snippet. It is a not-very-short script but does the job in my case.

> Prerequisites (and macro variable)

```
proc sql noprint;
select distinct var2 into:var2s separated by ','
from work.test1
order by 1;
quit;
```

> Actual splitter

```
%macro dssplit;
%do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(%superq(var2s)));

%let varsplit = %sysfunc(strip(%scan(%superq(var2s), &i, %str(,)))); *making sure to get rid of erroneous spaces;

proc sql;
create table testsplit&i._%sysfunc(compress(&varsplit.)) as 
select * from work.test1
where var2 = "&varsplit.";
quit;

%end;

%mend dssplit; %dssplit;
```

This, in your case, will create datasets with names `testsplit1_a` & `testsplit2_b`.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to do with call execute, assume that your data has been sorted.

```
data _null_;
    set test1;
    by var2;
    if first.var2 then call execute(
       'data data_'||strip(var2)||';
           set test1;
           where var2="'||strip(var2)||'";
        run;');
run;
```

**Edit:**

```
data _null_;
    set test1;
    by var2;
    if first.var2 then do;
        n+1;
         call execute(
       'data data_'||strip(n)||';
           set test1;
           where var2="'||strip(var2)||'";
        run;');
    end;
run;
```

Comment: It works, thank you! for the final generated data, is it possible to name it as data_1, data_2, data_3,...instead of the data_var2, because I need to use the output to do some downstream analysis. or do you have solution to call it? eg. Data_new1; set data_a;run; Data_new1; set data_b;run;

Comment: It works on the test data but doesn't work on my real data. In my real data set, I have already had a variable called n. The output data name turned to be data_7, data_16, data_512 etc. (7,16 are the original n values from the output data)

Comment: Use `_n_` and not `n`